# How to get the edges of a 3D Delaunay tessellation with CGAL?

Tags: c++, cgal, delaunay

The question is clear from the title. I tried a ton of variants of

```
  const DT3::Finite_edges itedges = mesh.finite_edges();
  for(DT3::Finite_edges_iterator eit = itedges.begin(); eit != itedges.end(); eit++) {
      const CGAL::Triple<DT3::Cell_handle, int, int> edge = *eit;
      edge.first->vertex((edge.second+1) % 3)->info();
      edge.first->vertex((edge.third+1) % 3)->info();
  }
```

but none has worked (I tried `% 2`, `% 4`, `+2`, etc).

I'm able to get the tetrahedra and the triangles. Of course I could extract the edges from them but that would require to remove some duplicates.

Comment: I found. This is `edge.second % 4` and `edge.third % 4`.

Comment: why use `+` or `%` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use addition or modular arithmetic. The solution is simpler:

```cpp
  const DT3::Finite_edges itedges = mesh.finite_edges();
  for(DT3::Finite_edges_iterator eit = itedges.begin(); eit != itedges.end(); eit++) {
      const DT3::Edge edge = *eit;
      const DT3::Vertex::Info v1_info = edge.first->vertex(edge.second)->info();
      const DT3::Vertex::Info v2_info = edge.first->vertex(edge.third)->info();
  }
```

The documentation of the nested type `Edge` is [here](https://doc.cgal.org/5.4/TDS_3/classTriangulationDataStructure__3.html#af31db7673a6d7d28c0bb90a3115ac695) as well as in the [section "Representation" of the user manual of 3D Triangulation Data Structure](https://doc.cgal.org/5.4/TDS_3/index.html#TDS3secintro).

---

Edit: note that I have chosen to respect your coding style, ignoring modern C++ features. Using C++11 features, I prefer to write it this way, using [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```cpp
  for(const auto edge: mesh.finite_edges()) {
      const auto v1_info = edge.first->vertex(edge.second)->info();
      const auto v2_info = edge.first->vertex(edge.third)->info();
  }
```